# how to get facebook profile information using json in android

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the name of school from this type of json :

```
"username": "blah",
       "education": [
          {
             "school": {
                "id": "[removed]",
                "name": "[removed]"
             },
             "year": {
                "id": "[removed]",
                "name": "[removed]"
             },
             "type": "High School"
          },
          {
             "school": {
                "id": "[removed]",
                "name": "[removed]"
             },
             "year": {
                "id": "[removed]",
                "name": "[removed]"
             },
             "type": "College"
          }
       ]
```

here is my code :

```
JSONObject obj=null;
URL img_url;

String jsonUser = facebook.request("me");
obj=Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
String id=obj.optString("id");
String name=obj.optString("name");
```

what should i write the code to get the education fields school name ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Facebook fb = new Facebook(API_KEY);// ... login user here ...JSONObject me = new JSONObject(fb.request("me")); String id = me.getString("id");
```

Comment: but i want to get the specifically { "school": { "id": "[removed]", "name": "[removed]" }   its name only

Comment: try this http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/09/android-facebook-integration.html

Comment: dude my code is working basically i m not able make you understand  thing is that i wanted to get the only "school name" from the education field. i am asking how to get that thing possible as education field in facebook is a array list type object.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var schoolname =  yourobject.education.school.name
```